# My RPi 2 Model B will not detect the keyboard or my mouse?

Tags: pi-2

My RPi 2 Model B will not detect the keyboard or my mouse, the mouse I have is a logitech m185 with a iPazzport mini wireless keyboard. During a bootup of my RPi i noticed a red word that said FAILED on the boot-up screen and it won't detect the keyboard or mouse. What should I do to resolve this error and prevent it in the future?

Comment: Have you tried unplugging and plugging them back in while the system is running?  Can you access the system to do some diagnostics any other way (e.g., ssh)?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are not meeting the power requirements for the Raspberry Pi 2.

The Raspberry Pi Foundation recommends at least 1.8w of power for the Rpi2.

Not having enough power can cause seemingly random behavior like you are describing.

Please see here for details for more details.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 separate USB devices that are failing it might be hardware.